# Function loop comparing three variables to three values contained in a nested array to find best match

Tags: javascript, function, associative-array

I have been a lurker on this site for a while while I have been designing a small program in JavaScript. I have run into an issue that I cant seem to solve though, and I need your help!

You can find my question at the bottom of the post. in layman's terms, I need help setting up a function loop to compare three values against three values in a nested array, where each value can be compared to all three values in the array.

I am working on a type of calculator to find the best way to cut a 3D rectangular piece of material to get the best yield, given a certain cut size I need. I have many different potential sizes of material to cut from, sorted in a nested array, like this: 
data[i][x] where i = number key of material arrays available, and x(each array) is set like so 
[material ID#, height, width, length, volume]

What I have is a cut size i need to cut out of the parent material, which consists of: height, width, length.

The problem I have run into is the best way to align the cut size in the parent material (comparing each value against the other: height, width, length) to return the highest yield possible.

I will mention that I do have a few **constraints**.

First, whatever lines up in the height measurement in the parent material can only be 1 cut size tall. The other two dimensions (length and width) can be multiple sizes each if they fit.

so, to reiterate constraints:

**Height must be 1 unit.**

Width can be multiple units

Length can be multiple units

The orientation of the cut piece does not matter, so long as these constraints are held to.

*Length or width can be a decimal, but only whole cut sizes will count.*

Below, I have placed some code I designed to do this, but the problem is it is not nearly dynamic enough, as you can see. it only compares height to height, width to width, and so forth.

The input for this is as follows:

```
cutheight;
cutwidth;
cutlength;
data[i][x]; // each nested data array is like so: [material ID key, height of material, width of material, length of material, volume of material]



for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if((data[i][1] > cutheight) && (data[i][2] > cutwidth) && (data[i][3] > cutlength)) {
    insertSort(results, data[i], (Math.min((data[i][4] * (Math.ceil((numCutPiecesNeeded) / ((Math.floor(data[i][2]/cutwidth)) * (Math.floor(data[i][3]/cutlength)))) ) ))) ); // the last step in this function determines pieces yielded per material
    }
}
function insertSort(array, match, materialVolumeMin){
//itterate through the results and see where the new match should be inserted
    for( j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
    // if the billetVolumeMin of match is less than the materialVolumeMin of the item at position j
        if(array[j][5] > materialVolumeMin){
        //insert the match at position j
        array.splice(j, 0, match);
        array[j].push(materialVolumeMin);
        return true;
        }
    }
    // if the materialVolumeMin of match is not less than anything in array then push it to the end. This should also cover the case where this is the first match.
    // push match
    match.push(materialVolumeMin);
    array.push(match);
    // set match index 5 to the materialVolumeMin for future comparison
    //array[array.length -1].push(materialVolumeMin);
    return true;
}
```

What this code does is return all the nested arrays with a new value attached to the end, which is in effect the total volume of material needed to get the cuts you need out of it. I use this volume as a way of sorting the arrays to find the most cost effective (or highest yield) material to use.

I believe this is more of a logic question, but I have no idea how to do this. I do know that it would be better to have multiple cuts available on the height axis as well, but due to various factors this is not possible.

I also believe that the height should be found first, by comparing all three dimensions of the cut size to the parent material, and finding the one that has the least waste

How I see this maybe happening:

```
Math.min((data[i][1]-cutheight), (data[i][1]-cutwidth), (data[i][1]-cutlength));
```

From there, I really dont know. I appreciate any and all help, advice, or suggestions. Thank you!

Edit: I dont think I was clear in my Question. The code above is how im going about the problem now, but is by no means how I want to actually do it in the finished program.

My question is: 
How can I set up a function to compare my three sizes to each possible material size in my nested array, and return the best match, where data[i][5] (which is data[i][4] (volume of material) times the number of cut pieces I need, divided by how many fit in said parent material) is the smallest out of all of my possible choices.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: If you don't have a particular question and just want your code reviewed, you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: My question is how can i set up a function to compare the cut sizes against each of the values in my associative array. right now i have a one to one comparison, that does not compare against all possible dimensions.